# Easiest way to create and upload a self-signed certificate to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, powershell, command-line-interface, azure-cli

I'm looking for some CLI commands or a script of some sort that I can execute to do the following in one step

1. create a self-signed certificate
2. upload it to my Azure App Service
3. create an app setting param with the certificate thumbprint as value

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***1. Create a self-signed certificate***

If you want to create a self-signed certificate, we can use  [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) to implement it. For more details, please refer to [here](https://gist.github.com/princeppy/d00bad66d9caac86d9b7d3ce9e35fc12) and [here](https://linuxize.com/post/creating-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate/)

a. Create the certificate key and the signing (csr).

```
openssl req -new -x509 \
            -newkey rsa:2048 \            
            -sha256 \
            -days 3650 \
            -nodes \
            -out example.crt \
            -keyout example.key \
            -subj "/C=SI/ST=Ljubljana/L=Ljubljana/O=Security/OU=IT Department/CN=www.example.com"
```

The fields, specified in `-subj` line are listed below:

- `C=` - Country name. The two-letter ISO abbreviation.
- `ST=` - State or Province name.
- `L=` - Locality Name. The name of the city where you are located.
- `O=` - The full name of your organization.
- `OU=` - Organizational Unit.
- `CN=` - The fully qualified domain name

b. Generate the certificate

```
openssl pkcs12 \
            -inkey example.key \
            -in example.crt \
            -export -out example.pfx \
            -password pass:<your password>
```

> ***2. Upload it to my Azure App Service and save the certificate thumbprint in Azure App service app settings***

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

```
az login

# Upload the SSL certificate and get the thumbprint.
thumbprint=$(az webapp config ssl upload --certificate-file $pfxPath \
--certificate-password $pfxPassword --name $webappname --resource-group $resourceGroup \
--query thumbprint --output tsv)

# save thumbprint 
az webapp config appsettings set --name $appName --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --settings "Certificate _Thumbprint=$thumbprint"
```

[image]
[image]